# What is the ".android" folder in C:\Users\Username and can it be deleted?

Tags: android, android-studio, file

There is a folder ".android" in C:\Users\Username. It takes up 21GB of my storage. I used to use android studio but no longer use it. Is it safe for me to delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the folder is related with the SDK, your `21GB`, are probably from your emulators, check your `.android\avd\` directory.
You can delete the dir, but your emulators will be lost (you can create it again)